# React/enzyme - How to test reference function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have a component that contains input that has assigned function to ref and I try to write test for it:

```
 <input
   id="input-element"
   type="checkbox"
   checked={isChecked}
   ref={(input) => {
       if (input) {
           input.indeterminate = true;
       }
   }}
   className="checkbox" />
```

And my question is how check in test if the input indeterminate is set to true. Documentation https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/ref.html didn't help me because there are only very simple and useless examples.

I tried to test it so:

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);
expect(wrapper.find('#input-element').prop('indeterminate')).toBeTruthy();
```

But `wrapper.find('#input-element').prop('indeterminate')` returns me `undefined`

Answer (score 5):

If all you care about is testing the ref setting callback and not the ref component itself, I've figured out a way to do this with a `shallow` rendered component by mocking the ref:

```
const mockRef = {};
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>);
const inputElement = wrapper.find('#input-element');
inputElement.getElement().ref(mockRef)
expect(mockRef.indeterminate).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: This actually works for testing REF assignment and avoids mounting the component.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

From Enzyme github:

You might have noticed the ShallowRenderer doesn't have docs for a ref() mehthod, while the MounedRenderer does. If you want to test refs you have to mount.

I believe the reason is that shallow rendering does not maintain an internal instance and therefore it can't hold a ref. That is the purpose of shallow rendering. Even FB ReactTestUtils shallowRendering doesn't work with refs.

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/316

You need to use `mount` instead of `shallowMount`.

check here also:

https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/ref.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [the React docs section on Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs), "React will call the ref callback with the DOM element when the component mounts".

`shallow` does not do a full DOM render so the component is never mounted and the Callback Ref is never called.  To ensure the Callback Ref is called you will need to do a full DOM render with `mount`.

[Starting with v2.7](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#270-december-21-2016) `Enzyme` provides [`ReactWrapper.getDOMNode`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html#getdomnode--domcomponent) as part of the [Full DOM Rendering API](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/mount.html).

You can use `mount` in combination with `ReactWrapper.getDOMNode` to get access to the DOM node and test for `indeterminate` like this:

```jsx
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent {...props} />);
expect(wrapper.find('#input-element').first().getDOMNode().indeterminate).toBeTruthy();  // SUCCESS
```

Comment: is there any way for testing the useLayoutEffect, tried using shallow and mount didnt worked any suggestions on this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59157804/testing-uselayouteffect-using-jest-and-enzyme-for-window-resize?noredirect=1#comment104541097_59157804

Answer (score 0):

May Be you can try like this:
when you wrote more complex code then you need to write complex tests also, I hope this helps you.

```
handle = (e) => {
   // indeterminate = true;
   // whatever you what to do
}

<input
   id="input-element"
   type="checkbox"
   checked={isChecked}
   ref="inputRef"
   onChange={() => this.handle()}
   className="checkbox">
```

Testing code

```
const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent {...props}/>);
const inputElement = wrapper.find('#input-element').prop();
expect(inputElement.ref).toEqual("inputRef");
inputElement.onClick();
// your condition I'm not sure
// expect(indeterminate).toBeTruthy();
```