# Testing useLayoutEffect using Jest and Enzyme for window resize

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks

I am trying to test a functional component in that functional component when I do the resize of the window I am calculating the height using useLayoutEffect.

The feature is working, but I was not able to find a proper doc for testing with hooks.

So what I have tried is

app.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import App from "..";

describe("App Page", () => {
    it("should render App Page", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });

    it("should adjust the height on window resize", () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
        global.innerHeight = 600;
        global.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
        console.log(wrapper.debug()); // how can i test the useLayoutEffect
    });
});
```

app.js

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { Layout } from "antd";
const { Header } = Layout;

function useWindowSize() {
    const isClient = typeof window === "object";

    function getSize() {
        return {
            width: isClient ? window.innerWidth : undefined,
            height: isClient ? window.innerHeight : undefined,
        };
    }

    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState(getSize);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isClient) {
            return false;
        }

        function handleResize() {
            setWindowSize(getSize());
        }

        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount and unmount

    return windowSize;
}

const App = () => {
    const headerRef = useRef(null);
    const size = useWindowSize();
    const [barHeight, setBarHeight] = useState(56);

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        setBarHeight(headerRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }, [size]);

    return (
        <Layout className="layout">
            <HeaderContainer ref={headerRef}>
                <Header>.....</Header>
            </HeaderContainer>
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Should I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@testing-library/react-hooks for these or is there any way to test it using Enzyme itself.

Comment: try with `mount()`, shallow renderer has known issues with running `useEffect`

Comment: @skyboyer using mount how should i test, when i tried to access the ref it was throwing error

Comment: @skyboyer as airbnb documents suggest "NOTE: can only be called on a wrapper instance that is also the root instance." since i am running for a functional component does it have any instance only for class components only instances will be there isn't, correct me if am wrong

Comment: @skyboyer tried this one also didnt worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57805917/mocking-refs-in-react-function-component